# How to map over Dataset and Array to generate new rows (gives Dataset[Array[Point]] not Dataset[Point])?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following function which I want the result has the type of `Dataset[Point]` or `Array[Point]`. But it returns `Dataset[Array[Point]]`.

Also, I want to filter the result by the `Point.Point >= 8`. Where is the best place to call the filter function?

```
  def compare2(dbo: Dataset[Cols], ods: Array[Cols]) = {
    import dbo.sparkSession.implicits._
    dbo.mapPartitions(p => p.map(l => ods.map(r =>
      Point(l.Id, r.Id, getPoint(l, r))))
      //.filter(p => p.Point >= 8) // p is Array[Point]
    )
  }

case class Cols (Id: Int, F1: String, F2: String, F3: String)
case class Point (Id1: Int, Id2: Int, Point: Int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use flatMap:

```
 dbo.mapPartitions(p => p.flatMap(l => ods.map(r =>
   Point(l.Id, r.Id, getPoint(l, r))))
  .filter(p => p.Point >= 8) // p is Array[Point]
```

You are basically converting each cols to an array of points because the last portion is a map from array[Cols]=>Array[Points]. If you flatmap it will make the dataset flatten these arrays to elements. Once you do this the filter should work properly.

Comment: This is the right idea, but perhaps you meant `dbo.mapPartitions(p => p.flatMap(l => ods.map(r =>` ?

Answer (score 2):

`dbo.mapPartitions` requires a `func: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U]` (removed the implicit `Encoder` to make things clearer).

> **mapPartitions[U](func: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U]): Dataset[U]** Returns a new Dataset that contains the result of applying func to each partition.

That gives that `p` inside `mapPartitions` is of type `Iterator[Cols]`.

`p.map(l` gives `l` of type `Cols` and the result of type `Iterator[T]`.

With that you are producing `Iterator[Iterator[T]]`, but that's not enough :(

Since `ods: Array[Cols]` the part where you do `ods.map(r` gives `Array[Point]`.

Taking it all, you have a huge mental task to understand what's going on here and could be rewritten to the following code:

```
dbo.mapPartitions { p: Iterator[Cols] =>
  p.map { l: Cols => 
    ods.map { r: Cols => 
      Point(l.Id, r.Id, getPoint(l, r) } } }
```

To make things easier (esp. for future readers of your code), I'd recommend doing another rewrite using Scala's [For Comprehension](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/for-comprehensions.html):

> Scala offers a lightweight notation for expressing sequence comprehensions.

With that I'd suggest the following:

```
dbo.mapPartitions { p: Iterator[Cols] =>
  for {
    l <- p
    r <- ods
  } yield Point(l.Id, r.Id, getPoint(l, r))
}
```

Filtering is then very simple and would require a single `if` as part of the for comprehension.